# Two reports to be made into one

Tags: join

I'm a novice at Oracle and SQL Server but I had created two simple reports. One that gives the 'No. of Orders' per Customer that each Agent made and another report that gives the 'No. of Receipts' per customer that each Agent secured.

**This pic shows the 'No. of Orders' report and the No. of Receipts Report**
[image: http://imgur.com/SJ8xxtn]

I would like them combined to show No. of Orders and No. of Receipts per Customer that each Agent made and secured. If no orders, then show 'No Orders' and if no receipts for that customer by that agent then show 'No Receipts'.

A simple join will not compute as the number of rows of Orders per agent may not be equal to the number of rows of receipts per agent.

I would like the report to show like so:.
[image: http://imgur.com/xKUDCVG]

## Code for No. of Orders Report :

```
SELECT
 Name_Of_Agent
,COUNT(Order_Number) NO_OF_ORDERS
,Customer_Name

FROM Orders

WHERE 
    WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
AND trunc(ORD_ENTRY_DATE) between 
    to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 

GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name

ORDER BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
```

## Code for No. of Receipts Report :

```
SELECT
 Name_Of_Agent
,COUNT(RCPT_NUM) NO_OF_RCPTS
,Customer_Name

FROM Receipts

WHERE 
    WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
AND trunc(RCPT_ENTRY_DATE) between 
    to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 

GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name

ORDER BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
```

What code can I use to join them together and also print 'No Orders' or 'No Receipts' consecutively ?

Comment: Which language?  TSQL or PLSQL?

Comment: You know, I don't even know. I'm assuming it is TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the unrefactored way of doing it. Not knowing you tables or the data this is about as clean as I can get it.

What I'm doing is joining your two queries, like you surmised. First joining COUNT_OF_ORDERS subquery to COUNT_OF_RECEIPTS subquery, which will miss an Agent/Customer combinations that only exist in COUNT_OF_RECEIPTS, which you also noted. So I then union in nearly the same query, but I join from COUNT_OF_RECEIPTS to COUNT_OF_ORDERS and then only select results where COUNT_OF_ORDERS subquery had NULLs.

```
SELECT
    t1.Name_Of_Agent,
    t1.NO_OF_ORDERS,
    t2.NO_OF_RCPTS,
    Customer_Name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
             Name_Of_Agent
            ,COUNT(Order_Number) NO_OF_ORDERS
            ,Customer_Name
        FROM Orders as 
        WHERE 
            WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
            AND trunc(ORD_ENTRY_DATE) between 
                to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 
        GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
    ) T1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
             Name_Of_Agent
            ,COUNT(RCPT_NUM) NO_OF_RCPTS
            ,Customer_Name
        FROM Receipts
        WHERE 
            WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
            AND trunc(RCPT_ENTRY_DATE) between 
                to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 
        GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
    ) t2 ON
        t1.Name_Of_Agent = t2.Name_Of_Agent AND
        t1.Customer_Name = t2.Customer_Name

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t1.Name_Of_Agent,
    t1.NO_OF_ORDERS,
    t2.NO_OF_RCPTS,
    Customer_Name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
             Name_Of_Agent
            ,COUNT(Order_Number) NO_OF_ORDERS
            ,Customer_Name
        FROM Orders as 
        WHERE 
            WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
            AND trunc(ORD_ENTRY_DATE) between 
                to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 
        GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
    ) t1

    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
             Name_Of_Agent
            ,COUNT(RCPT_NUM) NO_OF_RCPTS
            ,Customer_Name
        FROM Receipts
        WHERE 
            WareHouse_Code = 'W1'
            AND trunc(RCPT_ENTRY_DATE) between 
                to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 
        GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent, Customer_Name
    ) t2 ON
        t1.Name_Of_Agent = t2.Name_Of_Agent AND
        t1.Customer_Name = t2.Customer_Name
WHERE
    t1.Name_Of_Agent IS NULL
```

I'm thinking of a cleaner way to do this where distinct AGENT/Customer combinations are determine from both queries first and then joined back into each table, which should not only give quicker results, but also a more digestible SQL statement. I'll post when my brain starts working again.

UPDATE: This should be exactly equivalent to the query above, but it's much prettier and should be a smidge faster.

```
SELECT
    AG_CU.Name_OF_Agent,
    Count(Orders.Order_Number) as COUNT_OF_ORDERS,
    Count(Receipts.RCPT_NUM) as COUNT_OF_RCPTS,
    AG_CU.Customer_Name
FROM
    (
        /*This will get a list of unique customer/agent combinations in both tables*/
        SELECT
            NAME_OF_AGENT,
            Customer_Name
        FROM
            Orders
        WHERE
            Warehouse_Code = 'W1' AND
            trunc(ORD_ENTRY_DATE) between to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 

        UNION

        SELECT
            NAME_OF_AGENT,
            Customer_Name
        FROM
            Receipts
        WHERE
            Warehouse_Code = 'W1' AND
            trunc(RCPT_ENTRY_DATE) between to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 

    ) AG_CU

    /*Join in Orders*/
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON
        AG_CU.Name_Of_Agent = Orders.Name_Of_Agent AND
        AG_CU.Customer_Name = Orders.Customer_Name AND
        Warehouse_Code = 'W1' AND
        trunc(Orders.ORD_ENTRY_DATE) between to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 

    /*Join in receipts*/
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON
        AG_CU.Name_Of_Agent = Receipts.Name_Of_Agent AND
        AG_CU.Customer_Name = Receipts.Customer_Name Warehouse_Code = 'W1' AND
        trunc(Receipts.RCPT_ENTRY_DATE) between to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') 
GROUP BY Name_Of_Agent,Customer_Name
```

Comment: Thank you very very much sir. I used this code with a few modifications; using a CASE and got it to print 'No Orders' or 'No Receipts' respectively.

But the code was right and I am very very grateful for your help. Thank you very very much.